# Cluster nodes cannot ping the external networks (like google.com)

Tags: networking, cluster

I have a cluster with 1 login node and 100 computation nodes.

I can ping the external networks including google.com from the login node. However, I cannot from the computation nodes.

The computation nodes are all reachable (ping) from each other.
They can also ping the login node. (and vice versa)

Where should I check first? (I am using CentOS 7)

The below is some info of my network status

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `net.ipv4.ip_forward` set to 1 on the login node (which I assume is acting as a router for the compute nodes)? Have you set up NATing (i.e. is `iptables -t nat -L` empty)?

Check `/etc/sysctl.conf` for `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`, and if it's not there, add it and run `sysctl -p` to source the changes you've made.

Comment: yes right. the login node acts as a route for compute nodes. I found that net.ipv4.ip_forward was set to 0. I changed it to 1 and the computes node can access the external networks now! (I don't know how it worked before).

Comment: Additionally, 'iptables -t nat -L' shows no entry. But all the policy for (PREROUTING, INPUT, OUTPUT, POSTROUTING) is set to ACCEPT.

Comment: You might also want to add `-t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE` to your iptables where `ens3` is your public facing interface.